# How do I pass a parameter to a Javascript .done function from a .success function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do I pass data from a .success function to a done function?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Bifrost/SetLanguagesTiefling",
    success: function () {
        var count = 4;
    },
    error: function () { alert("SetLanguagesTiefling"); },
    type: 'POST'
})
.done(function (count) {
    SaveLanguages(count);
})
```

Comment: May be, like the way you have given? Your question is vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if I declare count as a global variable and then assign values to count within local scope.

```
var count;
$.ajax({
    url: "/Bifrost/SetLanguagesTiefling",
    success: function () {
        count = 4;
    },
    error: function () { alert("SetLanguagesTiefling"); },
    type: 'POST'
})
.done(function () {
    SaveLanguages(count);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the `.done` function separately, you can use the `success` function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Bifrost/SetLanguagesTiefling",
    success: function () {
        var count = 4;
        SaveLanguages(count);
    },
    error: function () { alert("SetLanguagesTiefling"); },
    type: 'POST'
});
```

Comment: But how is it different than setting same code in `done()` callback?  EDIT: oops sorry, i miss that OP was already using `success` option

Comment: @A.Wolff There's no difference. The `count` value is in local scope of `success` function, so it is accessible. `:)` Does it make sense?

Comment: Ya ya, i see it now ;)